# Adding a horizontal rule between caption and lstlisting inside a tcolorbox

Tags: listings, captions, tcolorbox

I have example listings for a book.

[image]

I'd like a horizontal rule the width of the tcolorbox between the caption and the listing.

The code used to produce it:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{captionbox}{cmyk}{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}

\tcbset{colback=captionbox!5!white,colframe=captionbox!75!black}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\begin{tcolorbox}[toprule=3mm]\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}

\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,skip=10pt}

\lstset{numbers=none}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Sample code block]
This is a code block
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

My only constraint is that I need to use the listings package and lstlisting because Pandoc requires that for listings. I am happy to replace anything else to produce the same effect of a box around the caption and listing with the rule between the caption and listing and a similar style feel.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. Did you tested? And I think that the figure doesn't correspond to code. Where is title box (`Sample code block`) defined?

Comment: @Ignasi My apologies - I must have culled too much when I tried to make a MWE. I've updated it to code that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: changed `overlay first` to `overlay unbroken and first` for the line to also appear in unbroken boxes. My mistake.

Too bad you can't use `tcblistings`, which seems to have been made specifically for this purpose and internally uses `listings` (I've read but not verified this).

Although I do not like "specific" solutions (i.e. solutions which need manual fiddling), I nonetheless propose this to you simply because it "works":

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{captionbox}{cmyk}{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}

\tcbset{%
    colback=captionbox!5!white,%
    colframe=captionbox!75!black,%
    top=1mm,%   %% Used to manually align the caption with the horizontal line
    %
    %% Create a new "style" for your titled listings tcolorbox
    mylistingwithtitle/.style = {%
        breakable,%
        %% Use tcolorbox's internal tikz object name (frame) to draw a horizontal line
        overlay unbroken and first={\draw[shorten >=1.4pt, shorten <=1.4pt] ([yshift=-3em]frame.north west) -- ([yshift=-3em]frame.north east);}%
    }%
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, toprule=3mm, mylistingwithtitle]%
    \vskip-.5\baselineskip%
}

\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,skip=15pt}


\begin{document}

%% This following line is only useful to execute \lipsum[1-4] inside the listing
\lstset{numbers=none, escapeinside={(*}{*)}}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Sample code block]
  This is a code block

  (*\lipsum[1-4]*)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

If you change the caption formatting, you will need to manually fiddle with the vertical spacing, i.e the `top=1mm` option for the tcolorbox and the `[yshift=-3em]` to draw the horizontal line. You will also have to fiddle with the latter option, along with the `shorten >=1.4pt` and `shorten <=1.4pt` options, if you decide to change the formatting (top line, border width, inner margins, etc.) of the tcolorbox.

I took the liberty to add the `breakable` option to the tcolorbox to allow it to break over several pages.

Output:

[image: Output produced by above code]

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for humoring my specific constraints!