# Listings: line number separator rule

Tags: listings, rules, line-numbering

Here I found a similar question with horizontal rule, which answer I don't understand to a degree I could use it to solve my problem:

[Adding a horizontal rule between caption and lstlisting inside a tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228621/adding-a-horizontal-rule-between-caption-and-lstlisting-inside-a-tcolorbox)

---

I am looking for a **separator rule for line numbers** when the **frame rule** has **already** been **extended** to include the line numbers (Would be nice if it was possible with just the listings package).
See this example:

**[Listings: recognize numbers and `1e-3`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235783/listings-recognize-numbers-and-1e-3)**
[image: sample]

---

### Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{ipython_frame}{RGB}{207, 207, 207}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{iPython}{
    commentstyle=\color{cyan}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    %
    rulecolor=\color{ipython_frame},
    frame=single,
    frameround={t}{t}{t}{t},
    framexleftmargin=6mm,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{halfgray},
    %
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=iPython]
import math
import numpy as np
from lib.analytical import csa

sin2_theta  = np.sin(theta)**2
+= -= *= /= + - * / ? < > & % == <=
# += -= *= /= + - * / ? < > & % == <=
def test(a=100, b=True):
    <= >= == 2 + 3j * 7e-3
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: That is already there! Just see the second linked question [Listings: recognize numbers and `1e-3`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235783/listings-recognize-numbers-and-1e-3). I added the words "minimal working" so it might become more of an eye-catcher.

Comment: On this site, each question should be more or less standalone and should have its own MWE (when appropriate). Besides, the question you link to contains code that is far from minimal for the present question.

Comment: The MWE is not the complete language definition anymore, but just code with some frame.

Comment: That's much better :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly... Do you need a vertical line between line numbers and the the code? If no, please specify exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, a line between line numbers and code. However, the frame is used already to create the outer frame, so `frame=leftline` would overwrite these settings.

Answer (score 3):

A rather *hacky* solution is to use [tcolorbox](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for the border so that you can use listings `frame` for the rule. `Tcolorbox` provides a library for boxes that contain `listings` and `minted` codes. Below is a minimal setting but you have lots of room for improvement since `tcolorbox`es are highly customizable:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{ipython_frame}{RGB}{207, 207, 207}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}

\lstdefinelanguage[]{iPython}[]{python}{
    commentstyle=\color{cyan}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    %
    rulecolor=\color{ipython_frame},
    frame=l,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{halfgray},
    xleftmargin={0.75cm},
    %
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcblisting}{boxrule=1pt, listing only,listing options={language=iPython}}
import math
import numpy as np
from lib.analytical import csa

sin2_theta  = np.sin(theta)**2
+= -= *= /= + - * / ? < > & % == <=
# += -= *= /= + - * / ? < > & % == <=
def test(a=100, b=True):
    <= >= == 2 + 3j * 7e-3
\end{tcblisting}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Which will give you this:

[image]

A quick note on defining new language in listings: You can use a base dialect for the new language so you don't need to define all the keywords from scratch.

```
\lstdefinelanguage
   [[hdialecti]]{hlanguagei}
   [[hbase dialecti]{hand base languagei}]
   {hkey=value listi}
   [[hlist of required aspects (keywordcomments,texcs,etc.)]]
```

hence `\lstdefinelanguage[]{iPython}[]{python}`.

Comment: This package seems to be either badly documented or corrupted. If I copy the command for "*Producing tcblisting Environments*" `NewTCBListing` I am getting an error. -> It has to be lower case `newtcblisting`. "*Producing tcbinputlisting Commands*" however is not working at all for me. Then you never really know what code is actually necessary or producing which part of the examples... I am a bit lost searching for the `tcbinputlisting`.

Comment: Turns out this 'kinda works':
 `\newtcbinputlisting[]{iPython}{
 colframe=ipython_frame, colback=ipython_bg,
 left=0pt, top=-9pt, bottom=-9pt, boxrule=0.4pt, 
 listing only,
 listing options={language=iPython},
 }{}`
Yields an error though, not being able to find `document.listing(.tex)` when I try to use `\iPython{test.py}`.
Input is crucial, since it's a good way to keep an oversight of different source codes right after another, imho.

Comment: @hillbilly, sorry, but I'm not sure what are you asking in your comment. Can you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to describe it further. See [tcolorbox.18.5](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#subsection.18.5).  I would like to use `\newtcbinputlisting` to create a `lstinputlisting`-like command, which yields the above mentioned error though. The final product should be an style-file for iPython that I can reuse with a simple `input` and `environment` command.

Comment: @hillbilly, I am not on a computer and it is rather difficult to answer it without a computer. I suggest you to post a new question to get the help of others and perhaps getting an answer quicker. I'll be back in few days and I'll try to answer this. cheers!

Comment: I just did so: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236966/listings-tcbinputlisting

Comment: bump - I just had a look at this again and wondered if you knew the solution to this last problem which did not attract enough attention to be answered. (Usage of the tcbinputlisting command)