# lstlisting environment with caption on the first line separated with a dashed border

Tags: xetex, listings, tcolorbox

Still on my way to write my own LaTeX class file. My today's purpose is to write an environment similar to [the result available here, in the Arch Linux Media Wiki.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RAID#Update_configuration_file)

[image]

My question is deeply linked with [the solution proposed to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228827/66964).

Imagine an lstlisting environment, with the caption of the lstlisting glued with the environment itself. The lstlisting env and the caption must both have a simple border (frame), the border between the caption and the env is dashed.

The environment and the caption do not have the same font. In my case, the font I use for the lstlisting env is defined as it:

```
\setmonofont{Bitstream Vera Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

The caption must not be breakable from the environment. Currently, without using tcolorbox, in the example below, if I remove the newpage statement, the caption may be broken (and will be if you put some text after the section title).

I would like to have the line numbers *inside* the `lstlisting` environment and ideally, when we copy-paste the text from the `lstlisting` environment itself, the numbers do not have to be copied.

I still need to be able to use

```
moredelim={[is][keywordstyle]{@@}{@@}}
```

as environment parameter to my `lstlisting`, because I want to be able to specify some statements used to put some text in bold for example. As my LaTeX documents are mainly focused on IT technical documentation, I still want to be able to put an emphasis on some words or characters.

So the idea is to keep to use `lstlisting` directly and put inside some `tcolorbox` declarations.

In the future, the purpose is obviously rewrite a wrapper around the different `lstlisting` I have and have one different for standard files, code files with line numbers, code snipped without line number, configuration files, etc.

Here is my minimum working example I have from now. After having compiled with XeLaTeX, you can see the first to environments are using `tcolorbox` and the last ones are the 2 examples I tried to make before @Johannes_B (on TeX friends' chat) advised me to use `tcolorbox`. As you can see, this is deeply inspired from the aforementioned answer.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Bitstream Vera Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins}
  \tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{captionbox}{cmyk}{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}

%\tcbset{%
%    colback=captionbox!5!white,%
%    colframe=captionbox!75!black,%
%    top=1mm,%   %% Used to manually align the caption with the horizontal line
%    %
%    %% Create a new "style" for your titled listings tcolorbox
%    mylistingwithtitle/.style = {%
%        breakable,%
%        %% Use tcolorbox's internal tikz object name (frame) to draw a horizontal line
%        overlay unbroken and first={\draw[shorten >=1.4pt, shorten <=1.4pt] ([yshift=-3em]frame.north west) -- ([yshift=-3em]frame.north east);}%
%    }%
%}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{%
%    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, toprule=0mm, mylistingwithtitle]%
    \begin{tcolorbox} [enhanced, colback=white] %, toprule=0mm, mylistingwithtitle]%
%    \vskip-.5\baselineskip% 

    \tcblower

}

\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\end{tcolorbox}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing}

\lstset{
    moredelim={[is][keywordstyle]{@@}{@@}},
    basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    breakautoindent=false,
    breakindent=0pt,
}


\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth\relax}{0.4pt}\par\vskip1pt#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
    format=listing,
    singlelinecheck=false,
    margin=0pt,
    font={sf},
    labelsep=space,
    labelfont=bf}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[2][]{%
    \lstset{%
        frame=single,        
        numbers = left,
        caption = #2,
        #1,
    }%
}{}

\lstnewenvironment{someTest}[1][]{%
    \lstset{%
        frame=top,
        frame=bottom,
        #1,
    }%
}{}

\begin{document}

%% This following line is only useful to execute \lipsum[1-4] inside the listing
\lstset{numbers=none, escapeinside={(*}{*)}}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Sample code block]
  This is a code block

  @@Hello world@@

  (*\lipsum[1-4]*)
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!25,left=6mm,
        listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}}}
    This is a \LaTeX\ example which displays the text as source code
    and in compiled form. Additionally, we use line numbers here.
\end{tcblisting}

\newpage
\section{Objective}


\begin{code}{Some great caption}
    Hey there, you see the border above is a bit shorter and has 2 borders missing.
\end{code}

\begin{someTest}[caption=Some great caption]
    Without vertical border, the caption border is just fine
\end{someTest}


\end{document}
```

Comment: do you need to allow page breaking within the listing?

Comment: You can define your own `tcblisting` environment where you can specify all options possible for `listings` as well -- no need to mix them additionally, in my point of view

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yep. Because for now, in my technical documentation, I have several long lstlistings containing whole configuration file content, or some long snipped of code.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've read the documentation from tcolorbox too. I've seen that ability to define (inherit from) the tcolorbox environment, but when I wanted to specify `moredelim={[is][keywordstyle]{@@}{@@}}` as a parameter to that environment, this didn't work.
I think too, tcolorbox has been designed in a way to avoid mixing both environment, as tcolorbox can use feature from listings directly.
If you find a way to achieve that in my use case, let me know.

Comment: @wget: I've some familiarity with `tcolorbox` but I am not aware of any way and feature. I'll try and I do not find another way, I'll leave a note to the package author Thomas Sturm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

The style is 'very' special, in my point of view!

```
\documentclass[oneside]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Bitstream Vera Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins}
  \tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{captionbox}{cmyk}{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01}


\newtcblisting[auto counter]{wgetlisting}[2][]{%
  listing only,
  breakable,
  top=0.5pt,
  bottom=0.5pt,
  colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!25,
  left=6mm,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=1pt,
  toprule=1pt,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  listing options={%style=tcblatex,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black},
    moredelim={[is][keywordstyle]{@@}{@@}},
    basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    breakautoindent=false,
    breakindent=0pt,
    escapeinside={(*}{*)},
  },%
  lefttitle=0pt,
  coltitle=black,
  colbacktitle=white,
  title={Listing \thetcbcounter:  #2},#1%  
  borderline north={1pt}{14.4pt}{red!25,dashed},
}
% 


\begin{document}


\begin{wgetlisting}{Sample code block}
  This is a \LaTeX\ example which displays the text as source code
  and in compiled form. Additionally, we use line numbers here.

  @@Hello world@@
\end{wgetlisting}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a way to remove the same text in the last part of the lstlisting? I only need the one that is formated (with @@ interpreted).
And I checked page breaks are supported \o/ great!

Comment: @wget: Ah, ok, I thought you want to have it -- Add the option `listings only` to the option list in the definition of `wgetlisting`

Comment: @wget: Sorry, I meant `listing only`, not `listings only`

Comment: Ok. I began to implement my own version, but I realized I've an issue. Like precised in my question, when I try to copy the text from the lstinline environment, the numbers are copied too. I was hoping your solution did integrate that requirement, but it isn't :-( Do you have any idea to circumvent or fix that issue?

Comment: @wget: No, I haven't, unfortunately. And please don't change my answers. Just make a suggestion and I would have changed it

Comment: Ok thanks anyway. Btw, I've just seen in the tcolorbox package some examples where numbers are not copied when I try to make a copy-paste. Gonna investigate.
And regarding the edit, no problem.

Comment: Ok I've made some debugging. The lines numbers which are copied are due to the `title` statement. As soon I remove it, the numbers are not copied when I select the text in the listing environment. I tried to tweak that line (especially the counter) but no changes. That line still prevents the numbers from being *not* copied. Any idea?

Comment: Do you know why such code refuses to be compiled? https://goo.gl/5f84k5
while with a plain lstlisting environment, it does?

Comment: @wget: I had no time to look, actually

Comment: Ok. Replacing {1.2\baselineskip} by 14.4pt solved all the issues I reported: the ability to select the content of the lstlisting environment without copying the numbers with it and the ability to have long special code inside the tcolorbox environment without crashing the document. Still some tests to do and add xkeyval support to the command to specify the language before validating the answer.

Comment: @wget: `xkeyval` was not in your request ;-)

Comment: Of course, I didn't cite xkeyval explicitly ;-). But I didn't know I wouldn't be able to specify the language to the environment as the `listing options` are nested in the tcblisting environment options. When I wrote about wrappers, the environment I would like to have is one the most generic possible regarding the language in it. I think it's my job now to implement such feature. ;-)